# Get Recipients List from Email C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a plugin and I want to check if the recipients to an email are of a certain type. I've found the "to" is an `ActivityParty` type and I cant seem to get the individual recipients from the list. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using early-bound classes? Visual Studio intellisense should help you find the properties of `ActivityParty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed this using the code below:

```
EntityCollection Recipients = email.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to");

foreach (var party in Recipients.Entities)
{  
var partyName = party.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid").Name;
var partyId = party.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid").Id;

…
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually 'To' is list of ActivityParty entities. Every ActivitParty object contains PartyId property which is EntityReference.
So, if you want to find entity type of email receiver(or receivers) try with next code:

```
Email email;
...
IEnumerable<ActivityParty> emailRecievers = email.To;
foreach (ActivityParty ap in emailRecievers)
{
    string entityTypeName = ap.PartyId.LogicalName;
    if (entityTypeName == "contact")
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added your code and I get a message saying that email does not contain a definition for 'To'. I have added in my CRM as a Service Reference which I thought would have made this work, but it seems like I am still missing something